# return type of (fmap.fmap) func vs fmap (fmap func)

Tags: haskell

following is the sample code I am testing

```
import Control.Exception

safeLoad :: FilePath -> IO (Either IOException String)
safeLoad f = (Right <$> readFile f) `catch` (pure . Left)

fileChars :: FilePath -> IO (Either IOException Int)
fileChars = fmap (fmap length) . safeLoad

fileChars' :: FilePath -> IO Int
fileChars' = (fmap.fmap) length safeLoad

example :: [Maybe Integer]
example = (fmap.fmap) (+1) [Just 2,Just 3]
```

here the type of `(fmap.fmap)` evaluates as:

```
ghci> :t ((fmap.fmap) length)
((fmap.fmap) length)
  :: (Functor f1, Functor f2, Foldable t) =>
     f1 (f2 (t a)) -> f1 (f2 Int)
```

the type of `(fmap (fmap ...))` also is:

```
ghci> :t (fmap (fmap length))
(fmap (fmap length))
  :: (Functor f1, Functor f2, Foldable t) =>
     f1 (f2 (t a)) -> f1 (f2 Int)
```

but why does `fileChars'` return `IO Int`  while `fileChars` return `IO (Either IOException Int)`?

Comment: The two are equivalent since `(x . y) z` is equivalent to `x (y z)`.

Comment: Thank you I understand that but my question here is why `fileChars` and `fileChars'` have different return types despite being equivalent expressions.

Comment: Beware! In `fileChars'`, `length` is iterating over an `Either IOException` (applied to `String`), not a `[]` (applied to `Char`)! It will always return `0` (for `Left`) or `1` (for `Right`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because

```
fileChars' = (fmap.fmap) length safeLoad
           = fmap (fmap length) safeLoad
```

while

```
fileChars = fmap (fmap length) . safeLoad
```

Mind the dot. The two expressions are *not* equivalent.